# Find a line (and column) of xml_node in rapidxml

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

From what I could understand in the docs I deducted every [`xml_node` knows it's position in the source text](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1lifetime_of_source_text). What I'd like to do is to retrieve LINE and COLUMN for given `xml_node<>*`:

```
    rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("generators.xml"); // Open file, default template is char

    xml_document<> doc;               // character type defaults to char
    doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());;    // 0 means default parse flags
    xml_node<> *main = doc.first_node();  //Get the main node that contains everything
    cout << "My first node is: <" << main->name() << ">\n";
    cout << "   located at line " << main->?????() << ", column " << main->?????() << "\n";
```

How should I retrieve those offsets? Could I somehow crawl from the `main->name()` pointer back to the beginning of the document? But how can I access the document string from `xml_document<> doc` to compare offsets?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you parse a simple xml document in a string.

```
char xml[] = "<hello/><world/>"

doc.parse(xml);
```

RapidXML will insert null terminators (and maybe make other mods to the "document", so it might look like this now:

```
char xml[] = "<hello\000\000<world\000\000";
```

If you than ask for the `name()` of the 'hello' node, it returns a pointer to the 'h' in your `xml` array. You can just subtract the base of the array to get an offset.

```
int offset = node->name() - &xml[0];
```

Obviously this isn't line and character. To get that, you'd need to count the number of newlines between the offset and the array start. (but maybe do this on a 'clean' version of the xml data, as RapidXML might well mangle newline sequences in the processed version..

Comment: In your example above, it would be `xmlFile.data()`. Does that make sense? I guess you're using `rapidxml_utils.hpp` for `rapidxml::file`

Comment: Yep. But I really wanted to get the data out of the *node*. I want this so that I can easily return errors containing line and column where XML has incorrect data. If it's not possible to get this out of the node, I'd need to pass the original string all along which is a little bit annoying.

Comment: @TomášZato You could locate the top of the document by iterating up the `node->parent()`s. Then use the `name()` method to get the address of the start of it's name. (Beware of whitespace being trimmed or compacted, when counting newlines - the "non-destructive" mode might help you)